How can I ensure external links open in a new tab?
I recently had to solve a problem where my theme was preventing the attributes of a menu link from displaying. I didn't know the problem at first. I problem solved first by trying various modules and lastly the menu_link_attributes module, which should have worked, but still no attributes would appear.
This post is a post of the problem which I developed an answer for. As I couldn't find anything which tries to solve a Drupal 10 theme template problem like this I will post both the problem and the answer here, starting with the problem I solved.
I eventually checked my theme and the twig template was not generating the attributes at all.
This forced me to embark on a process of solving how to modify the menu--main.html.twig template, specifically where the anchor tag <a> is generated.
As I had the menu_link_attributes module enabled I figured I would solve for these two parts at the same time and also allow for the code to degrade well when the module was not installed.
So this is what I needed to solve for:

Include attributes from menu_link_attributes (which were missing)
Include logic to insert target="_blank" when menu_link_attributes had not set it AND when external link was true.

I am working with Drupal 10.3.2

Obligatory UX warning: if you interfere with people's browsing, especially their ability to use their own "back" button, they might not be inclined to carry on using your site. See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5397/whats-your-take-on-target-blank, https://www.nngroup.com/articles/new-browser-windows-and-tabs/, . Marketers continue to be painfully, painfully slow in realising that this is an anti-pattern; it's your duty as a developer to push back ;)

Back to the Back button!

Opening external links in a new tab is also what the External Links module does (using JQuery).

@PatrickKenny, yes I did try the module and i am sure it works. My unique situation was that the theme i am using had not included the links attributes value within the anchor tag in the twig template. If it had then External Links module and Menu Link Attributes module both would have worked out the box. In solving the twig template problem I also went ahead add added the logic directly.

@Clive, UX is important, thanks for your feedback. It can be argued that ensuring the user does not completely disappear from the website is important for marketing stickyness and converting. It is possible the user would not return otherwise. This was the thinking I always held until I read your link. There are many valid points made. I never considered the mobile user difficulty of external links, for this reason alone I am reconsidering this strategy in future. Nonetheless it was a good exercise to learn more about Twig ;)

@avpaderno, i see you changed the title. IMO the value of the post was in the fix of a theme. I felt this angle was the benefit of my post as there are already many posts highlighting the fix with External Links Module and Menu Link Attributes module. What if the user did not know the twig theme template was at fault? I would say this is relevant to the title and changing it detracts from the posts value. What are your thoughts?

For your Q #1, your comment about confirming the template rendering makes sense. But might be agnostic in consideration of a specific attribute.
Your approach in the menu.twig is intriguing. However, for Q #2, it may be worth considering consistency among links not only in the menu, but links entered in content and by other methods. For a consistent UX across your site, JS is going to be the way to go.
Here's a JS approach:
It does a couple of main things. It sets an outlink icon to provide a visual indicator to users that they are following an external link and adds the target attribute to the link to open a new tab. You could pick and choose either as needed.
(function outlink() {
  "use strict";

  var i,
    olIcon,
    olLinkList,
    olDisclaimer,
    olIconSize,
    olIconColor,
    olSelector,
    olSiteName,
    olClass = "outlink",
    olClassIgnore = "outlink-ignore",
    olIconStyle =
      "margin: 0 0.25rem; display: inline-block; vertical-align: baseline;",
    olNewWindow = false,
    Drupal = window.Drupal;

  window.outlink = outlink;

  // Stub out Drupal.t translate method if this is used on a non-Drupal site
  if (typeof Drupal === "undefined") {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    Drupal = {};
  }
  if (typeof Drupal.t === "undefined") {
    Drupal.t = function t(text) {
      return text;
    };
  }

  // Set disclaimer text after site name is known
  if (location.hostname === "") {
    olSiteName = Drupal.t("this site");
  } else {
    olSiteName = location.hostname.replace("www.", "");
  }

  // Set CSS selector with exclusions
  olSelector =
    "a[href^='http']" +
    ":not(." +
    olClassIgnore +
    ")" +
    ":not([href*='//" +
    olSiteName +
    "'])" +
    ":not([href*='//www." +
    olSiteName +
    "'])";

  olDisclaimer = Drupal.t("This link is external to ") + olSiteName;

  if (olNewWindow === true) {
    olDisclaimer += Drupal.t(" and will open in a new browser window or tab");
  }
  olDisclaimer += ".";

  // Select all links with stated selector
  olLinkList = document.querySelectorAll(olSelector);

  if (olLinkList) {
    for (i = 0; i < olLinkList.length; i++) {
      addRel(olLinkList[i]);
      if (olNewWindow === true) {
        // open all external links in new windows
        addOpener(olLinkList[i]);
      } else {
        // prevent external links from opening in new windows
        removeOpener(olLinkList[i]);
      }

      // catch icon color overrides
      olIconColor = "#6b6b6b";
      if (olLinkList[i].dataset.iconColor) {
        olIconColor = olLinkList[i].dataset.iconColor;
      }

      // catch icon size overrides
      olIconSize = 12;
      if (olLinkList[i].dataset.iconSize) {
        olIconSize = olLinkList[i].dataset.iconSize;
      }

      // do not apply icons to links with images inside
      if (olLinkList[i].innerHTML.indexOf("<img") === -1) {
        // create Base64 icon to spec
        olIcon = buildIcon(olIconColor, olIconSize);

        // add icon to link
        addIcon(olLinkList[i], olIcon, olIconSize);
      }
    }
  }

  function addOpener(element) {
    element.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  }

  function removeOpener(element) {
    element.removeAttribute("target");
  }

  function addRel(element) {
    element.setAttribute("rel", "noopener noreferrer");
  }

  function addIcon(element, icon, size) {
    // create icon image element
    olIcon = document.createElement("img");
    olIcon.setAttribute("src", icon);
    olIcon.setAttribute("style", olIconStyle);
    olIcon.setAttribute("alt", olDisclaimer);
    olIcon.setAttribute("title", olDisclaimer);
    olIcon.setAttribute("width", size);
    olIcon.setAttribute("height", size);

    // add image inside link
    element.appendChild(olIcon);
    element.classList.add(olClass);
  }

  function buildIcon(color, size) {
    var olIconCode =
      '<svg width="' +
      size +
      '" height="' +
      size +
      '" viewBox="0 0 768 768" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill="' +
      color +
      '" d="m640 640h-512v-510.09l128-1.91v-128h-256v768h768v-320h-128zm-256-640 128 128-192 192 128 128 192-192 128 128v-384z"/></svg>';

    // Base64 encode SVG for increased IE/Edge support
    olIconCode = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(olIconCode);

    return olIconCode;
  }
})();

About:

External site links (outside of current domain) show icon, disclaimer, and optionally open in new window/tab
Explicit notice of new window/tab behavior is read aloud by assistive technology to satisfy WCAG 2.1 – 3.3.2 On Input
Adds rel="noopener noreferrer" to link tags for security and performance improvements:

About rel=noopener

If window.opener is set, a page can trigger a navigation in the opener regardless of security origin.


The performance benefits of rel=noopener

Linking to another page using target="_blank" will run the new page on same process as your page. If the new page is executing expensive JS, your page's performance may suffer.


[MDN]Link types: noreferrer

instructs the browser, when navigating to the target resource, to omit the Referer header and otherwise leak no referrer information




Disclaimer text and alt text pulls in current domain name (with fallback to "this site")
Inlined external link icon as SVG
Vanilla JavaScript, no dependencies
Adds class="outlink" to all processed links
Looks for class="outlink-ignore" on link tag to skip processing

This script conditionally injects an external link icon, with alt text of "This link is external to {URL}." This is available to the Accessibility Object Model and to assistive technology.

To start off with I used have Devel installed and debugged by inserting the dsm(variable) tag where a menu item was being generated, the twig insert was:
{{ dsm(item.url) }}

This printed to the message field on the page which made debugging easy.
In the below code in between the two {# LINK ATTRIBUTE UPDATE #} comments you will find the modifications I made to the theme menu--main.html.twig template
To implement the required logic in the Twig template while ensuring that the code does not break if the menu_link_attributes module is uninstalled, I added a condition to check for the existence of item.url.options.attributes. Additionally, I checked for the presence of the target attribute and added target="_blank" if it is not set and if item.url.external is true. #}
Below is the code that worked for me, I hope it helps someone else. This code is from one of the Gavias themes, I kept the whole code from the page for better context.
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul {{ attributes.addClass('gva_menu gva_menu_main') }}>
      
    {% else %}
      <ul class="menu sub-menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      {% set class_mega_menu = '' %}
      {% set class_columns = '' %}
      {% if item.attributes.gva_layout == 'menu-block' and menu_level == 0 %}
        {% set class_mega_menu = 'gva-mega-menu mega-menu-block' %} 
      {% elseif item.attributes.gva_layout == 'menu-grid' and menu_level == 0 %}   
        {% set class_mega_menu = 'gva-mega-menu megamenu menu-grid' %} 
        {% set class_columns = ['menu-columns-', item.attributes.gva_layout_columns]|join('') %}
      {% endif %}    
      {%
        set classes = [
          'menu-item',
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
          item.attributes.gva_class,
          class_mega_menu,
          class_columns
        ]
      %}
      <li {{ item.attributes.addClass(classes)|without('gva_icon', 'gva_class', 'gva_layout_columns', 'gva_block', 'gva_layout') }}>
        {# {{ dsm(item.url) }} #}

        {# LINK ATTRIBUTE UPDATE - START #}

        {# item.url.options.attributes Only exists with menu_link_attributes module #}

        {# Initialize link attributes as an empty string #}
        {% set link_attributes = '' %}

        {# Check if options and options.attributes exist #}
        {% if item.url.options is defined and item.url.options.attributes is defined %}
          {# Loop through url.options.attributes and build the attribute string #}
          {% for attr, value in item.url.options.attributes %}
            {# Add each attribute to link_attributes #}
            {% set link_attributes = link_attributes ~ attr ~ '="' ~ value ~ '" ' %}
          {% endfor %}

          {# Check for target attribute and add target="_blank" if external #}
          {% if not (item.url.options.attributes['target'] is defined) and (item.url.external is defined and item.url.external) %}
            {# Add target="_blank" to link_attributes #}
            {% set link_attributes = link_attributes ~ 'target="_blank" ' %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}

        <a href="{{ item.url }}"  {{ link_attributes|raw }} >{% if item.attributes.gva_icon != '' %} <i class="fa {{ item.attributes.gva_icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
          {{ item.title|trim }}{% if item.below or item.attributes.gva_layout == 'menu-block' and menu_level == 0 %}<span class="icaret nav-plus fas fa-chevron-down"></span>{% endif %}
        </a>
        {# LINK ATTRIBUTE UPDATE - END #}

        {% if item.attributes.gva_layout == 'menu-block' and menu_level == 0 %}
          <div class="sub-menu">{{ item.gva_block_content|raw }}</div>
        {% endif %}  
        {% if item.below %}{{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}{% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

